# Is it possible to use a DOM element in the same was as a check box in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm creating a scatterplot, and have appended 4 rectangles at the top to serve as a colour legend — each of the 4 rectangles is of a specific colour, and corresponds one of the 4 categories of data points.

I'd like users to be able to click on each of these rectangles, like a check box, and thereby fade the opacity of the data points in that category.

Forgive the fact that this is somewhat vague (I've never dealt with this sort of thing before, only mouseover event listeners, so am wondering )— is it possible to use DOM elements, like rectangles, as check marks? Are there any examples of this being used with D3?

Comment: As much as I know, DOM is about structure and you can create a rectangle using CSS for every element in your DOM. And Yes, you can create this behavior using CSS and Javascript

Comment: @Kiyarash sorry, can you give me something a little more concrete? Are there any code examples of this floating around? Do you have any pseudo code so that I can see what this should look like?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5d621a60e2d1d02086bf

Comment: look at this : https://jsbin.com/cerekeqejo

Comment: @Kiyarash hmm, it's a start, but I don't think I can use that. I was hoping to see how this would look using D3, with data; that code also doesn't allow me to "un-tick". The block that altocumulus posted is actually really similar to what I was thinking.

Comment: `EDIT` : https://jsbin.com/xocugenuze/1/edit?css,js,output

Comment: See chapter [*Multi-line graph with automatic legend and toggling show / hide lines*](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-multi-line-graph-with-automatic-legend-and-toggling-show--hide-lines) from *D3 Tips and Tricks*. Other examples are http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069, http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBar.html.

Comment: Or maybe this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/anPk11KpmODaBt9YLYgU?p=preview